Why am i getting different values from this_thread::get_id() and gettid()?
I was reading threads and concurrency and hit this quote:

std::this_thread::get_id() return the id of the thread calling it.

So, I wrote the following code to test the function and see if it's doing something else than what Uniux's gettid() does:
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

void someFunction(){
  int i = 0;
  while(i++ < 2){
    cout<<"TID using gettid(): "<< gettid()<<endl;
    cout<<"TID using this_thread::get_id: "<< this_thread::get_id()<<endl<<endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(900));    
  }
}

int main(){
  cout<<"Hello from main"<<endl;
  cout<<"TID using gettid(): "<<gettid()<<endl;
  cout<<"TID using this_thread::get_id(): "<<this_thread::get_id()<<endl<<endl;
  
  thread testThread(someFunction);
  testThread.join();

  return 0;
}

The output shows that the two functions are returning different values and my question is why? is this related to pths and pthreads?

Why do you expect to get the same?

@gerum Because they two are supposed to return the running thread id!

Perhaps pthread_self() will be a better match than gettid()?

gettid returns a number. std::thread::get_id() returns a class that can be copied, compared and printed but is not guaranteed to be anything number-like. So these are not even advertised as returning the same or compatible type. (and pthread_self returns an opaque value that officially supports only pthread_equal)

gettid is Linux-specific, C++ is OS-agnostic, it has to cover all possible OSes, even those where threads have no numeric IDs. For this reason std::thread::get_id() is defined to return an opaque value that has no meaning other than being unique per thread.

This is how get_id() is implemented in libstdc++: return thread::id(pthread_self());. The dupe explains the difference between pthread_self() and gettid() calls.

The gettid() is a Linux specific system call returning the thread ID of the thread calling it. The returning type is a pid_t (an integer) as written in the man page https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettid.2.html
There's no guarantee that this system call return the same number as the POSIX  thread ID.
The C++ function std::this_thread::get_id() is part of the C++ standard and it's completely different. It's purpose is to identify threads in different systems (not specifically Linux). Moreover, the type returned by this function is not an integer but it's a std::thread::id and you can print it to your console only because its << operator is overloaded.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/id

There's no guarantee doesn't really explain why the numbers are different. get_id() has some implementation on Linux, which translates into some C function call. std::thread::id is just a thin wrapper that is mostly irrelevant in this context.
